# Dúvida - Gerar string aleatória de 6 caracteres em PHP

Tags: php, string

Galera, como faço para gerar uma string igual a esta:

```
Z8Yjv.jpg
```

Eu fui pegar a foto de um usuário aqui do Stack-OverFlow e o nome da foto veio assim. Eu tinha pensado em algo assim:

```
<?php

$string = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";

echo substr(str_shuffle($string), 0, 6);

?>
```

Qual a probabilidade de se gerar a mesma string??...E caso seja errado dessa forma, então qual é o melhor jeito de se gerar??

Comment: Não tem sentido fazer isso. Basta usar um base64 (ou outro critério previsível) do ID da base de dados (ou qualquer contador sequencial), que não vai se repetir nunca.

Comment: @Bacco Tem razão, nem tinha pensado nisso..hehe, obrigado!

Comment: Outra maneira é fazer sua própria função, mas que gere sequencial: a, b, c, .... , x, y, z, A, B, C, .... Z, aa, ab, ac, ad... Similar ao que as planilhas fazem com a identificação das colunas. Continua na mesma lógica: você escolhe os caracteres, mas converte de uma sequência numérica que incrementa de 1 em 1, sem repetição (que, no final das contas, é exatamente o mesmo que encurtadores de URL e armazenadores de imagem fazem usualmente).

Comment: **Boa noite!**
da uma olhada neste link
https://www.vivaolinux.com.br/script/String-randomica/