# Criar código aleatório ao carregar a página PHP

Tags: php

Estou criando um sistema para uma imobiliária, preciso criar um código aleatório para cada inserção.

Exemplos: 
C para casa = C5241a4d / 
T para terreno = T77d4a1r

Eu quero jogar esse código em um input, para criar a pasta que receberá os arquivos, entre outras coisas.

Creio ser algo parecido com o exemplo abaixo:

```
    <?
$num = rand(1, 10);
  echo "O número gerado foi: " . $num;
?>
```

Gostaria de instruções.

Comment: Gostaria de entender o ponto negativo.

Comment: Não fui eu quem negativei, mas não ficou muito claro que instruções você quer. Respondi algumas coisas baseado no que entendi.

Comment: As pessoas deveriam explicar, ao invés de apenas negativar. Falta de senso isso.

Comment: Eu entendo seu ponto, é revoltante tomar um negativo sem haver explicação. Mas as vezes alguns usuários fazem assim por medo de represálias (o que infelizmente tem acontecido muito [inclusive já aconteceu e acontece comigo])

Comment: @AgênciaLaBarba eu formulei uma resposta https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/314187/3635, o ideal para evitar falhas ou conflitos é usar o ID do proprio imovel cadastrado (supondo que use auto_increment na tabela), então deixei um exemplo mais ou menos para gerar as pastas.

Comment: @WallaceMaxters, fico chateado, mas bola pra frente... trabalho bem no front, mas sofro um pouco no backend... enfim...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu não faria isto de forma alguma, não há garantias de "integridade", nomes podem se repetir misturando arquivos, pastas que serão vazias podem ser criadas e ficarem lá sem vinculo com o banco, outros problemas podem ocorrer assim (dependendo do sistema).

Dá pra resolver tudo se baseado na ID do item na tabela do banco de dados, quando você cria uma tabela em um formato razoável, geralmente na maioria dos tipos de banco você tem a coluna de ID, que geralmente é `AUTO_INCREMENT`, ou seja usar esta ID já vai resolver o problema.

Então ao cadastrar o imóvel, pegue a ID, por exemplo no momento de cadastrar o imóvel você usar insert, então logo após use `LAST_INSERT_ID`, algo como:

```
INSERT INTO imoveis (categoria, descricao) VALUES ('casa', 'foo bar baz');
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

Então você pode criar o nome de uma pasta baseada neste ID.

Claro que como você esta usando a API do PHP então poderia fazer tudo nela mesmo, pode criar uma função só pra gerar a pasta baseada na ID:

```
function GerarPasta($categoria, $id, $target) {
    $prefixo = strtoupper($categoria{0}); // Gera C (casa), T (terreno), A (apartamento)

    $path = $prefixo . str_pad($id, 10, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);

    if (!is_dir($path)) mkdir($path, 0755);
}
```

O uso seria:

```
GerarPasta(<categoria>, <id do banco do imovel>, <pasta aonde vai criar as pastas>);
```

Nesta função não gerei strings com formato estilo url do youtube, mas sim baseado apenas na ID, então imóveis com ids como 1, 2, 3, 4 e 100 vão gerar:

```
GerarPasta('casa', 1, '/foo/bar/');        // Gera pasta: /foo/bar/C0001
GerarPasta('terreno', 2, '/foo/bar/');     // Gera pasta: /foo/bar/T0002
GerarPasta('apartamento', 3, '/foo/bar/'); // Gera pasta: /foo/bar/A0003
GerarPasta('casa', 4, '/foo/bar/');        // Gera pasta: /foo/bar/C0004
GerarPasta('casa', 100, '/foo/bar/');      // Gera pasta: /foo/bar/C0100
```

Que acredito que já atenda bem ao seu caso, mas se quer mesmo um esquema de strings creio que deva usar a função assim:

```
function GerarPasta($categoria, $id, $target) {
    $prefixo = $categoria{0}; // Gera C (casa), T (terreno), A (apartamento)

    //Usando L gera em 32bit combinado com o "repetidor *"
    $packb64 = base64_encode(pack('L*', $id));

    //Remove qualquer caractere diferente de A-Z e 0-9
    $foldername = preg_replace('#[^\da-z]#i', '', $packb64);

    $path = $prefixo . $foldername;

    if (!is_dir($path)) mkdir($path, 0755);
}
```

> **Nota:** eu não testei a função, eu não sei se ela pode conflitar

Exemplos geram algo como:

```
GerarPasta('casa', 1, '/foo/bar/');        // Gera pasta: /foo/bar/CAQAAAA
GerarPasta('casa', 2, '/foo/bar/');        // Gera pasta: /foo/bar/CAGAAAA
GerarPasta('casa', 3, '/foo/bar/');        // Gera pasta: /foo/bar/CAWAAAA
GerarPasta('casa', 1000, '/foo/bar/');     // Gera pasta: /foo/bar/C6AMAAA
GerarPasta('casa', 1000000, '/foo/bar/');  // Gera pasta: /foo/bar/CQEIPAA
GerarPasta('casa', 10000000, '/foo/bar/'); // Gera pasta: /foo/bar/CGJAYAA
```

---

### Exemplo de uso:

Eu não sei como você fez o código, mas se usou preparedstatment deve ser algo semelhante a isto:

```
if (isset($_POST['categoria'], $_POST['descricao'])) {

    $categoria = $_POST['categoria'];
    $descricao = $_POST['descricao'];

    if (!$connection->prepare('INSERT INTO imoveis (categoria, descricao) VALUES (?, ?)')) {
       if ($prepared->bind_param('ss', $categoria, $descricao)) {
            if ($prepared->execute()) {
                 //Aqui pega a ID
                 $id_inserido = mysqli_insert_id($link);

                 GerarPasta($categoria, $id_inserido, '/home/user/public_html/'); //Cria a pasta
            } else {
                echo 'Falha ao executar a query';
            }
       } else {
            echo 'Falha nos parametros passados';
       }

       $prepared->close();
    } else {
         echo 'Falha no prepare';
    }
}
```

Comment: agradeço pelo seu tempo.  Na verdade, para explicar o que preciso fazer, é simples. Tenho procurado um código para adaptar de um "multi-upload", para montar esse esquema da imobiliária. Já faço um INSERT com PDO, tenho um upload de apenas um arquivo, e funciona perfeitamente. Pensei que, ao criar a pasta e vincular ao banco, conseguiria resolver esta questão. Em relação ao código postado, sendo C0001 para casa, por exemplo, já me serve bastante, pois posso criar um sequencial. Só não fiz isso no `AUTO INCREMENT`, pois não poderia usar letras com números, como já mencionou.

Comment: Enfim, para finalizar, vou tentar fazer a aplicação e testar. Prometo que volto com resultados, já que preciso entregar tudo até amanhã. Mais uma vez, obrigado pelo seu tempo, @Guilherme.

Comment: @AgênciaLaBarba mas a suas tabelas tem IDs já, ou não? Independente do sistema de upload.

Comment: Sim, tem o ID. Eu to quebrando a cabeça aqui, mas penso que devo fazer de forma separada o `INSERT`, usando `SESSION` talvez... cadastrar os detalhes, e depois mandar as fotos. Tenho um sistema de upload múltiplo, que cadastrar em uma nova tabela, mas cada foto com um `ID` diferente.

Comment: Então misturar sessão e fazer coisas assim só complica e vai cair naquilo que eu disse, você vai perder a integridade `integridade`, vai ser muito sugestível a problemas. Por isso elaborei a solução assim.

Comment: Eu vou ver com calma, te disse o que pensara outrora, mas mudei de opinião, depois de sua instrução.

Answer (score 1):

Vou dar uma opinião:

*Eu quero jogar esse código em um input, para criar a pasta que receberá os arquivos, entre outras coisas.*

Sério mesmo? Vai realmente confiar numa informação vinda do cliente (entenda "navegador").

Não é uma boa ideia usar um valor do `input` para criar uma pasta, baseada num valor vindo desse  input.

Mas respondendo objetivamente a pergunta: Você pode gerar valores únicos através de algumas funções do PHP como [`uniqid`](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.uniqid.php).

```
   $valor = uniquid()
```

Você pode passar no primeiro parâmetro um valor para ser o prefixo do código gerado, e no segundo parâmetro para "deixar mais único ainda", caso seja necessário.

Se você quer colocar isso num input, bastaria fazer algo como:

```
<input type="hidden" value="<?= uniquid() ?>" name="codigo_aleatorio">
```

Mas, com sinceridade, desconfiando para o fim que será utilizado, eu não aconselharia.

Se quiser ter um código único para criar uma pasta após submissão de formulário, use um valor na sessão, ou gera na hora do upload, ou qualquer outra coisa, exceto confiar no que vem do cliente pra fazer isso, [por questão de segurança](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/80699).

Comment: Obrigado pelas explicações. Eu preciso criar um código, mesmo que eu use apenas para referência de imóvel, utilizando essa lógica: se for uma casa, C74521201 (número aleatório). Vou seguir seu conselho, e não usar para outros fins. Estou com um problema para finalizar o upload múltiplo, pensei nessa como uma alternativa, jogar numa pasta e puxar depois... mas, vamos considerar apenas o código, para eu salvar o imóvel. Obrigado!

Comment: Wallace e @AgênciaLaBarba Eu pessoalmente não faria isso, o melhor seria pegar o ID do banco que é autoincremente e codificar no momento de exibir, com algo semelhante ao https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/266209/3635 - claro que neste caso poderia pegar a primeira letra do tipo do imóvel usando `$row['categoria']{0}` (variavel imaginaria). Assim desta forma provavelmente evitaria conflitos.

Comment: Pra constar Wallace em outra pergunta foi inclusive o que o Bacco sugeriu: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/281700/d%C3%BAvida-gerar-string-aleat%C3%B3ria-de-6-caracteres-em-php#comment575181_281700 - então - usar o ID, então tá ligado né? Se o Bacco disse é verdade :)

Comment: Só para sua solução não ficar muito perigosa. Na página do formulário, cria uma sessão com um token inserido. Algo como $rand(1,10) ; $token = sha1($rand); $_SESSION['token'] = $token; . Isso tudo inserido dentro de um hidden HTML
Daí na página de recepção do formulário, você cria uma regra de negócios para negar tokens inválidos. Se o $_POST['token'] for diferente de $_SESSION['toke'] {// Faça isso};

Comment: Lembrando que o uniqid se repete se chamar a função com intervalo muito curto de tempo (mais de uma thread/instancia apesar da gambiarra interna de fazer delay da implementação) ou se houver qq esquisitice com o controle de relógio da máquina (saiu do horário, e um ajuste de ntp sem drift ocorreu).

Comment: Perfeitos todos os comentários. Vou seguir as instruções, agradeço pelo vosso tempo. Assim que resolver esta questão, venho para trazer o que foi feito, para que seja referência à toda comunidade. Obrigado!!